# Check if a sentence or part of a sentence is a inside an other sentence

Tags: javascript, angularjs, loops, factories

I'm trying to get how much a sentence is inside another sentence.

For Example

I have 2 sentences:

- "This is the first"
- "I am the first "

In this example, the result i want to get is "the first" is inside both of the sentences.

I want to start my loop on the whole second sentence. I mean, that the first search will be if "I am the first " is inside "This is the first".
If not, check if "I am the " is inside, if not check "am the first".
Then split it to 2 words and so on...until I'm getting a match (or not)

What is the most efficient way to do it in JS?

Comment: Please show the loop you have.

Comment: Just to clarify my comment above, nobody is going to write a full code from the scratch to answer a "plese give me teh codez" question. Please show what you have tried so far, and explain what went wrong. Also, the requirements are bit vague. How about matching single words? How about multiple matches of sentences or words, should they occur only once in results?

Answer (score 0):

You can split both your strings into array.

```
var array1 = 'This is the first'.split(' ');
var array2 = 'I am the first'.split(' ');
```

Now you can loop over one array and find out if the word is in another array. And if a match is found then put it in another array and finally join the matched results separated by `space`

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo-code:

```
var array1 = sentence1.split(' '), array2 = sentence2.split(' ')
for(var array1length > 0; array1length--)
  for(array1.length to array1length)
    see if array1 subarray is inside of array2
```